# Adding A Col. That References A Lookup

Tags: sql-server, ddl

In SQL Server I have a main table that I want to add a column to. This column will hold an int that references the ID field of another table, a lookup:

```
Statuses
ID    Status
0     ''
1     'Destroyed'
2     'Reassigned'
```

I want to add a column (`StatusID`) to `MainTable`, type int, that can only hold values found in `Statuses.ID`.

`Statuses.ID` is a primary key (naturally).

I want it to be impossible to delete a row in Statuses that is referenced in `MainTable`.

I have tried all kinds of searches, but there are just too many details to be able to generate a good search.

————————————————————————

Results (09/21/17, 1306 PDT):

```
USE TIL
GO

ALTER TABLE TACI
    ADD StatusID INT;
```

(execute)

```
USE TIL
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.TACI
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_STATUS
    FOREIGN KEY (ID)
    REFERENCES dbo.Statuses (ID);
```

`Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 2
The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_STATUS". The conflict occurred in database "TIL", table "dbo.Statuses", column 'ID'.``

It would be nice to know what the conflict is...

`Statuses.ID` is `(PK, int, not null)`

`TACI.StatusID` is `(int not null)`. I created it 'null' then altered it to 'not null' when I got the error. Made no difference.

Comment: This is what a foreign key does. If you have the column defined as a foreign key you can't delete the lookup value if it is in use. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-foreign-key-relationships This is really the basics of referential integrity. I would suggest spending some time reading up on the topic as it is critical to create a solid database.

Comment: Of course I know that, Sean. I just do not know the DDL to accomplish this. It would be more helpful, if you know the DDL for this, to tell me that, rather than providing the name of what I need to do.

Comment: Well from your post it does not sound like you know what a foreign key is. You describe the behavior but never mention it. Perhaps instead of complaining to me that I didn't spoon feed you the code you could have read the link I posted. The syntax is in there quite clearly.

Comment: I read the link, it was unhelpful. It describes adding a FK, but not as part of adding a col. The crippled network here won't allow using designers (grr). As is so often the case the info. is pretty general, and doesn't address the actual task I have. I already have all the tables, so doing this as part of creating a table is not helpful, That's why I specified adding a col. to an existing tbl. And I don't want cascading to be possible. 

My OP was written to be specific, not using any technical terms, to forestall the cases where I intend one thing, but the reader gets a different idea.

Comment: A foreign key is a constraint on a column. So in your case you would add the column and immediately add the constraint. If you don't want to cascade updates or deletes you don't specify them. This is seriously about as basic as it gets for a foreign key. I don't understand why you can't implement this. If that link was unhelpful I feel bad for you because it describes exactly how to create a foreign key. And I would recommend not using designers for anything in sql server. Writing the code yourself is much faster and allows more precision.

Comment: Precision is a good thing, but there is a learning curve for the syntax, and pitfalls.

Comment: A learning curve for sure. What do you mean by pitfalls?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where the block is here but let me see if this is pretty much what you need. This accomplishes everything in your post and it is nothing more than adding a foreign key constraint.

```
create table Statuses
(
    StatusID int identity not null primary key clustered
    , StatusName varchar(50) not null
)

create table MainTable
(
    SomeColumn int identity
    , SomeValue varchar(50)
)

insert Statuses
select 'Status1' union all
select 'Status2' union all
select 'Status3'

insert MainTable
select 'Main table data 1' union all
select 'Main table data 2' union all
select 'Main table data 3'

select *
from Statuses

select *
from MainTable

--This should be what you state you have. Two tables with no foreign keys

--Now we add the new column
alter table MainTable
add StatusID int null

--Next we add our new foreign key constraint
alter table MainTable
add constraint fk_StatusMainTable foreign key (StatusID) references Statuses(StatusID)

--we need to populate the new column
update MainTable
set StatusID = 2 
where SomeColumn = 1

--There is no row in MainTable with a StatusID of 3 so this will work
delete from Statuses where StatusID = 3

--You cannot delete StatusID 2 because it violates the foreign key
delete from Statuses where StatusID = 2

--You cannot set the StatusID to 42 because it does not exists in the Statuses table
update MainTable
set StatusID = 42
where SomeColumn = 2

drop table MainTable
drop table Statuses
```